# SSRS Report : How to merge the two datasets in single tablix without having the relationship between the two datasets

Tags: sql, reporting-services, powerbi, ssrs-2012, msbi

SSRS Report :
How to merge the two datasets in single tablix without having the relationship between the two datasets.
Example :
Dataset 1 :10
[image]

Dataset 2 : -5

Result : 5

but the complex thing there is no common column or relationship between Dataset1 and Dataset 2.

Lookup ,Lookupset does not work because there is no relationship between the two datasets

Comment: You need to provide actual examples of what you are trying to do. Your description doesn't provide enough information.

Comment: You might be able to use UNION to join the 2 datasets with different values using the same columns.

Comment: Why is this tagged with SSIS? Tag should be SSRS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION ALL

```
select sum( colname) 
from (
  select  colname_dataset1
  from table_dataset1 
  union all 
  select  colname_dataset2
  from table_dataset2 
) t
```

You can use UNION ALL if you want merge all the rows for the two data set  or use UNION if you want the distinct result of the two dataset merge